# Is it possible to create a template of constructor?

Tags: c#

For example, I have a base class A and some subclass, B and C

```
public class A
{
    protected string data;
    public A(string s)
    {
        this.LoadFromString(s);
    }
    public virtual void LoadFromString(string s)
    {
        data = s;
    }
    public static T CreateInstance<T>(string s) where T : A, new()
    {
        T instance = new T();
        instance.LoadFromString(s);
        return instance;
    }

}
public class B : A
{

}

public class C : A
{

}
```

Now I want instance of B and C,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "111";
        //works
        B bb = B.CreateInstance<B>(s);
        //do not work
        C cc = new C(s);
        //do not work
        C cc = C.CreateInstance(s);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to define something in A to make one of the last to statement to work?

Comment: Just so you know, its "generics" in C#. Templates are a "C++" concept, and they do work slightly differently

Comment: Also note that your `B bb = B.Create...` line will not work as written.  The `B` class won't compile as-is.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to define something in A to make one of the last to statement to work?

No.  You would need to do something in `C` (add a constructor) to make the 2nd option work:

```
public class C
{
     // Note that this is required anyways - it won't compile without
     // a constructor that calls into base(string) anyways...
     public C() : base("") {}

     // This constructor will allow you to use new C(str)
     public C(string s) : base(s) {}
}
```

In order to make the third option work, you need to specify the type:

```
C cc = C.CreateInstance<C>();
```

This is because `C.CreateInstance` is actually exactly the same as `A.CreateInstance` in this case, so the above is compiled to the same thing as:

```
C cc = A.CreateInstance<C>();
```

There is no way in C# to create generic constraints which work against a constructor (other than the `new()` constraint, which requires a parameterless constructor).